# Lookup of values: create Javascript Object out of Array first or do use find()?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Objects, say:

```
myArray = [
{key: theKey0, value: theValue0},
{key: theKey1, value: theValue1},
{key: theKey2, value: theValue2},
...
]
```

and need to regularly lookup the value of a key,

Whats most performant, do I make a key/value Object first and then do the lookup (where I assume lookup is quicker)?

```
var myObject
myArray.forEach( i => {
   myObject[i.key] = value
})
// and then do multiple lookups
out0 = myObject[theKey0]
out1 = myObject[theKey1]
...
```

or do I use find directly each time?

```
out0 = myArray.find( i => i.key === theKey0 )
out1 = myArray.find( i => i.key === theKey1 )
...
```

Comment: _"Whats most performant"_ - depends on the environment and the machine. Consider doing your own performance metrics and tests?

Comment: @DBS I think the problem with the benchmark is that there are only 6 keys, so your first 6 objects in `myArray` will have these 6 keys. That ends up with`.find()` doing a max of 6 iterations before a match is found, so `myObject['f']` must be slower than `myArray.find(i => i.key === 'f')` when all `.find()` needs to check is 6 items, but if the order of `myArray` is more random, or there were more keys then the property access wins.

Comment: @NickParsons Ah, I thought I must have missed something, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, creating the object will be better in terms of speed, but worse in terms of memory efficiency, whereas calling `.find()` each time will be better in terms of memory (as you don't have an object consuming additional space), but worse in terms of speed.

A JavaScript object isn't just a dictionary, and the spec doesn't mandate that it needs to meet certain performance or complexity requirements for lookup (ie: it doesn't need to be O(1)). A decent browser/JavaScript engine however will strive to make object property lookup fast. Chrome's V8 for example uses an optimization known as [hidden classes](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties) to make property access quick. So using object property to lookup a value is much faster than iterating through the contents of an array each time.

Which option you choose doesn't really matter if `myArray` is small or the number of `out0`, `out1`, etc. variables you'll be creating is small.

[Quick example benchmark](https://jsben.ch/2qVUR)

Answer (score -1):

"Key / value" is the fastest search

Comment: What do you base this on?

Comment: Try to find in big data and judge according to the search time

Comment: My point is that maybe you should expand your answer a bit more. Perhaps link to what you used to reach this conclusion.